# standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error" kubernetes

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes

I know this issue has been encountered by many people, but none of the given answers resolved my issue.

### Workflow

- I run all my dockers in a kubernetes cluster (google cloud).
- I've setup the compilation_trigger to auto build my dockerfile when I commit in my master branch on github.
- Then I update my kubernetes deployment with `kubectl set image deployment/MYPROJECT MYPROJECT=eu.gcr.io/foo/MYPROJECT:$TRAVIS_COMMIT`

### Whats wrong ?

My pod stays in `crashloop back-off` and in the logs I read: `standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

### A bit of context

My workflow used to work untill the begining of June 2018, I don't understand what's wrong so Ive searched on the internet, modified my dockerfile, updated my dependencies, changed the dockerfile base image version, etc... Nothing works

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.10-alpine3.7 AS builder
ADD . /go/src/github.com/foo/MYPROJECT
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/foo/MYPROJECT/api
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-s -w" -a -installsuffix cgo -o /go/bin/api

FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/api /go/bin/api
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/foo/MYPROJECT/api/sql /go/migrations/sql
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/foo/MYPROJECT/api/.docs/swagger.yml /static/swagger.yml
RUN chmod +x /go/bin/api
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/api"]
```

#### [EDIT: 12 June]

I noticed the docker image size went from `6.3 Mo` to `2.3 Mo` when the problem started. I suspect an update from alpine, I continue to investigate.

Comment: Typically this means you're trying to invoke an executable compiled for a different platform. Is this really a 64-bit Intel/AMD Linux platform?

Comment: What does `file /go/bin/api` emit? If the file already exists in the working tree you `COPY`, `go build` won't recreate it, so if you were starting with, say, a MacOS binary in that position, then it wouldn't get replaced, and that would explain our error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I compile the binary in the first step, and the machine hosting the kubernetes node is a Container Optimized Os (by google). Plus, the file does not already exists in the tree... Im desperate

Comment: you have to figure out the arch of the hosting machine, and you need to see the arch type of the images you have, I have faced the same problem when I was running images compiled on  x64 on Rpi(arm), the solution was simply compiling in the hosting machine, or cross compiling with the right arch. 
another cause of such a problem is heterogenous cluster where the master node have different arch than that of workers, the images will be pulled according to the master.

Comment: ssh on the machine and `arch` gives `x86_64` and `uname -a` gives `Linux gke-teddycare-dev-default-pool-b1d4c5d3-2fnm 4.4.111+ #1 SMP Thu Apr 19 11:45:40 PDT 2018 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.60GHz`GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`. Im building for GOARCH=amd64 (?)

Comment: Again, what's the `file` output?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There is no `file` command, even when I switched to `golang:stretch`

Comment: For future note -- you can copy the binary out of the container and run `file` on your host.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue. I post it here, in case someone is stupid like me.
I made a change in my github repository, transforming 1 project/microservices into 1 monorepo for every microservices.
During the refactor, I had no package `main` in my `api` microservice, and the go build DID NOT fail, but wrote a file of `90 Ko` in the output destination.

#### SOLUTION

Ensure to have a main package

I feel really stupid but hey, it happens to everyone.

Thank you to commentators, you were right

Answer (score 0):

Although not the solution to this question, another cause may be if your command is a script without shebang.